# jQuery Ui not even creating ui elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

This is the first time I'm using jQuery ui. I followed this documentation https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ but it just doesn't work for me. When I ran same code in codepen it's working.

The autocomplete function is being executed without any error but it just doesn't creates the suggestion list (ul elements)

HTML:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}"> {{--jQuery UI For Autocomplete--}}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

  <script src="{{asset('assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js')}}"></script>
  <script src="{{asset('assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.js')}}"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="col ui-widget">
  <label for="create-affinity-id" class="font-weight-bold">Affinity Id</label>
  <input id="create-affinity-id" type="text" class="form-control" name="affinity_id" placeholder="Affinity ID">
</div>
```

Script

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var availableTutorials = [
      "ActionScript",
      "Bootstrap",
      "C",
      "C++",
    ];

    $('#create-affinity-id').autocomplete({
      source: availableTutorials
    });
  }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in console? Looks like you have the `head` setup.

Comment: there is an extra comma after the last element in the availableTutorials array.

Comment: I have your code working in a fiddle here. check for duplicate IDs on the page. https://jsfiddle.net/hs5xm62w/

Comment: No. I don't see any error. @twisty

Comment: I don't have any duplicate Id. I check the fiddle it's working but why not my code? @T3.0

Comment: Load jQuery UI js before  bootstrap.  Remove extra `}` from document.ready.

Comment: Voting to close because *It's caused by a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.*

Answer (score 1):

two syntax error extra `,` and extra `{`
replace js code with this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var availableTutorials  =  [
                            "ActionScript",
                            "Bootstrap",
                            "C",
                            "C++"
                        ];
                        $('#create-affinity-id').autocomplete({
                            source: availableTutorials
                        });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
    {{--jQuery UI For Autocomplete--}}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

    <script src="{{asset('assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>

    <div class="col ui-widget">
                <label for="create-affinity-id" class="font-weight-bold">Affinity Id</label>
                <input id="create-affinity-id" type="text" class="form-control" name="affinity_id" placeholder="Affinity ID">
            </div>

    <script>

$(document).ready(function(){
   var availableTutorials  =  [
                            "ActionScript",
                            "Bootstrap",
                            "C",
                            "C++"
                        ];

                        $('#create-affinity-id').autocomplete({
                            source: availableTutorials
                        });
                    
});

    </script>
```

Comment: Still not working for me but I can see the snippet works. What might be the other issues

Comment: can you send text or picture of chrome console window   press(F12)